# In Java, how would I convert from ASCII codes into their integers?

Tags: java, encoding

Suppose I have a `byte` array of integers. How would I go from those ASCII codes back to the real-world integers?

For example, if we read a simple text file of integers , like so :

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
```

...into a byte array, like this one :

```
boolean empty = true;
while (( readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
  for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++1) {
    Byte b = c[i];
    int xx = b.intValue();
    lastLine = xx;

    if (c[i] == '\n'){
      ++count;
      empty = true;
    } else {
        empty = false;
    }

  }
  }
  if (!empty) {
    count++;  
  }
```

Then once that file (which was just normal integers) gets put into the byte array.. if we then try to print it back to the screen again, it won't get print as number 5 , but as the ASCII code  -which is `53`

Just trying to wrap my head around this encoding topic, any tips appreciated thanks

thanks

Comment: Why do you read it into a `byte[]`? What's wrong with `String` or `char` to read a text file?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast from `char` to `int`. Something like,

```
char[] chars = "12345".toCharArray();
for (char ch : chars) {
    System.out.printf("%c = %d%n", ch, (int) ch);
}
```

Output is

```
1 = 49
2 = 50
3 = 51
4 = 52
5 = 53
```

Comment: hi Elliott, I updated my question a little . I'm not sure if maybe my new code helps you to see what I'm trying to do , thnaks

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
int asciiValue = 53;
int numericValue = Character.getNumericValue(asciiValue);

System.out.println(numericValue);
```

Comment: The nice thing about that method is that it not only works with ASCII digits, but also with fancy Unicode stuff as well as with letters ( "A" = 10, "B" = 11, and so on).  Something to watch out for if that is not what you want.

Comment: @dev , it works, but if the last number is 2-digits it only gets the ones-digit !!